# What statistical technique would be appropriate for optimising the weights?

Tags: optimization, statistics

**Background:**

For example I have the following data

```
headings = { 
         :heading1 => { :weight => 25, :views => 0, :conversions => 0}
         :heading2 => { :weight => 25, :views => 0, :conversions => 0}
         :heading3 => { :weight => 25, :views => 0, :conversions => 0}
         :heading4 => { :weight => 25, :views => 0, :conversions => 0}
       }
total_views = 0
```

I got to serve these headings based on their weightages. Every time a heading is served its `views` is incremented by one and `total_views` also incremented. And whenever a user clicks on a served heading its `conversions` is incremented by one. I've written a program (in Ruby) which is performing this well.

**Question:**

I need to **`Auto Optimize`** best converting heading. Consider the following views and conversions for all headings:

```
heading1: views => 50, conversions => 30
heading2: views => 50, conversions => 10
heading3: views => 50, conversions => 15
heading4: views => 50, conversions => 5
```

I need to automatically increase the weightage of heading(s) which is/are converting more and vice versa. The sum of weightage will always be 100.

Is there any standard algorithm/formula/technique to do this? There might be some other parameters that need to predefined before making these calculations. But I am not getting it through.

Pleas advise.

Thanks,

Imran

Comment: possible duplicate of [auto optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190738/auto-optimization)

Comment: Yes, but that question was closed as I only provided the link instead of explaining my problem in the question. That's why I created a new question.

Comment: In its current form, this isn't really a statistics question. Statistics is about drawing inferences about populations from data. Also, if you are trying to maximize conversions, is there a reason you wouldn't just serve the item with the highest conversion rate all of the time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple percentage calculation would do that.

```
30+10+15+5=60

30/60*100=50

10/60*100=17 (rounded)

15/60*100=25

5/60*100=8 (rounded)
```

So you get weightings of 50,17,25 and 8. You may or may not nead to watch out for rounding errors.

Comment: Jaydee thanks, yes this is calculating the weightage but what I am looking for is some standard technique/algorithm to auto optimize the weightage of best converting headings and vise versa.